# Как добавить библиотеку TelegramBots в Spring Boot проект?

Tags: java, telegrambots

Интересует вопрос написания бота с использованием фреймворка Spring Boot. В интернете предлагают использовать стороннюю библиотеку, но я ей не доверяю. Как добавить официальную библиотеку в проект напрямую?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить библиотеку `TelegramBots` можно напрямую.

Для этого Вам надо сделать сделующее:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplicationMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //добавить вот эту строку в запускаемый класс
        ApiContextInitializer.init();

        //АЛЬТЕРНАТИВА. У меня работает именно данный вариант
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            botsApi.registerBot(new YourBotClassName());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplicationMainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

Далее создать/отредактировать класс с вашим ботом. Ваш класс должен выглядить примерно вот так:

```
  //Добавить стандартный Spring Boot аннотацию
  @Component
  public class YourBotClassName extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    //Код бота идет тут
  }
```

Более подробную информацию можно найти в [FAQ официальной библиотеки](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/FAQ#spring_boot_starter)